# Looping in object arrays with each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the code below. I am trying to filter and get the index and value for the items item which contains similar input string, but it doesn't work.

```js
var items =[  {item:"Saab", sku:"SA"},
              {item:"Volvo", sku:"VO"},
              {item:"BMW", sku:"BM"},
              {item:"Toyota", sku:"TO"},
              {item:"Honda", sku:"HO"},
              {item:"Nissan", sku:"NI"},
            ];
            
$("#filter").keyup(function () {
    var filter = $(this).val();

    $(items['item']).each(function (index, value) {
        if (value.search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
          // Do somethign
        } else {
           console.log(index);
           console.log(value);
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="" />
    <span id="filter-count"></span>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: `$(items['item'])` is problematic.  `items` is an array, so the index is numercial, but you are trying to use a string for the index.  That's not going to return anything.  Secondly, `$()` should be given a selector string, so even if you were giving it the item property on one of your objects, it would not return results, as they are not valid selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to intake items as a regular javascript variable but not jquery selector.

```js
var items = [
  { item: "Saab", sku: "SA" },
  { item: "Volvo", sku: "VO" },
  { item: "BMW", sku: "BM" },
  { item: "Toyota", sku: "TO" },
  { item: "Honda", sku: "HO" },
  { item: "Nissan", sku: "NI" },
];

$("#filter").keyup(function() {
  var filter = $(this).val();

  items.forEach(function(item, index) {
    var value = item.item // Honda, Nissan
    var sku = item.sku // HO, NI
    if (filter !== '' && new RegExp(filter, "i").test(value)) {
      // Do somethign when matched
      console.info(index, value, sku)
    } else {
      // console.log(index);
      // console.log(value);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="" />
    <span id="filter-count"></span>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank Priya but how about the SKU?

Comment: `var value = item.item // Honda, Nissan`, same way `var sku = item.sku // HO, NI` inside `forEach`

Comment: I do not want to search in SKU, I actually want to search item and get SKU of that item

Comment: when matching, you can get the sku, `console.info(index, value, sku)`, if you add the above line from my comment. Updated snippet

Answer (score 1):

You can not use jquery each like this, change it to map as

```
items.map(function (value, index) {

        if (value.item.indexOf(filter) < 0) {
          // Do somethign
        } else {
           console.log(index);
           console.log(value);
        }
    });
```

```js
var items =[  {item:"Saab", sku:"SA"},
              {item:"Volvo", sku:"VO"},
              {item:"BMW", sku:"BM"},
              {item:"Toyota", sku:"TO"},
              {item:"Honda", sku:"HO"},
              {item:"Nissan", sku:"NI"},
            ];
            
$("#filter").keyup(function () {
    var filter = $(this).val();
    console.log(filter);
    items.map(function (value, index) {
        
        if (value.item.indexOf(filter) < 0) {
          // Do somethign
        } else {
           console.log(index);
           console.log(value.item + "-" + value.sku);
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="" />
    <span id="filter-count"></span>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lost Hien, but can I also let me know how I can get the sku of each item?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is caused by using jQuery selector to select array items, which will not work for Array or Objects, it will only work for DOM elements selection, here how you might do it using jQuery:

```js
var items = [
  { item: "Saab", sku: "SA" },
  { item: "Volvo", sku: "VO" },
  { item: "BMW", sku: "BM" },
  { item: "Toyota", sku: "TO" },
  { item: "Honda", sku: "HO" },
  { item: "Nissan", sku: "NI" },
];

$("#filter").keyup(function () {
  var filter = $(this).val();
  $.each(items, function (index, value) {
    $.each(Object.keys(value), function (idx, val) {
      if (val.search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
          // Do somethign
      } else {
       console.log(index, idx);
       console.log(value, val);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="" />
    <span id="filter-count"></span>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, the issue consists of this wrong access to array property:

`items['item']` that resolves to `undefined`

Indeed, the `item` property belongs to the objects contained in the `items` array and not to the array itself.

You have to iterate over the collection (with or without jQuery) and after access and use the property on every item:

```
$("#filter").keyup(function () {
    var filter = $(this).val();


    $(items).each(function (index, value) {
      console.log('value:',value)
        if (value.item.search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
          //do something
        } else {
           console.log(index);
           console.log(value);
        }
    });
});
```

If you don't want to use jQuery to loop over the collection:

```
$("#filter").keyup(function () {
    var filter = $(this).val();


    if(items.find(item => item.item === filter)) {
      console.log('found');
    } else {
      console.log('not found')
    }
});
```